# What is the 's' argument for in predict.glm() function?

Tags: r, predict, glmnet

I'm having trouble parsing the help files for the `predict()` function when using a `glmnet()`-defined model.  I don't see mention of an 's' argument anywhere.  However, in the example code below, it appears to be a way to feed a regularization parameter (often labeled lambda).

```
y_lasso = predict(lasso, X, s = lambda)
```

What is the `s` argument for, and where is it documented?

I have tried looking up help on `predict`, `glm.predict`, `glm.SafePrediction`, with no luck.

Comment: The `predict` method of `glmnet` objects is listed in the docs for the `glmnet` package, i.e. `?predict.glmnet`. Is there more to the question than where to find the documentation?

Comment: I was asking what the s parameter is for in glmnet, and I couldn't find it in the documentation.  I realize it may be a dumb question, and I should be better at finding the proper documentation, but it's certainly not an unclear one.  That being said, I'll add some carriage returns to make the exact question more prominent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/2.0-18/topics/predict.glmnet) for `predict.glmnet`.

> s - Value(s) of the penalty parameter lambda at which predictions are required. Default is the entire sequence used to create the model.